# Please recommend tools for PC, browser, home network performance problems?

Tags: performance, home-networking, benchmarking

My client is experiencing some odd response behavior in their browser for the past few days.  Classic, "nothing has changed" so I am starting at ground zero.  Browsing a website will timeout or take a ridiculous time to load -- other times, the same site and query is immediately responsive.  Once a connection is established, video streams are uninterrupted.

The home network hosts a website, but it is not experiencing any activity in Apache's 'access.log'

I am using speedtest.net to check if the ISP through the internet is 'OK' -- which looks typical (average +/-).  I have to suspect the home network is beaconing or something very abnormal, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Nine years later, this sort of question can be asked on your [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site. Given that it is likely to be a Windows PC, I would recommend system restore to the last restore point. And make sure that all such clients have system restore enabled for those "nothing changed" scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a problem with the DNS server: when the browser (any browser) tries to visit a "new" site, it first has to translate the host/domain name to an IP address, and this step can time out if the DNS server doesn't respond quickly enough.

Comment: njd, based on that, I just googled for some DNS tools and came up with 'dtrace' and I am watching the following video to learn.  Any other tools or sample scripts for dtrace??

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-8002801113289007228#

Answer (score 1):

A handy way to find out what the problem with networks like this is to use the Firebug http://getfirebug.com/ Extension in Firefox.

Then enable the **Net** tab and load up a website. Firebug will give you a list of all the activities involved in downloading that webpage and show you how long they took.

This page has a tutorial on using the Net tab:

www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/introduction-to-firebug-net-panel/

(not a hyperlink, cut and paste to get it - not enough rep *shrug*)

Comment: Oh thats good to know ... I use Firebug but I did not find that feature.  Good answer!